# Google Map v2 is not open for NEXUS 7 tablet

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2

I tried to install my android -studio apk in a tablet device with NEXUS 7 google and android verion 5.1.1. The app does not load my map at all and message displayed is "Application Stopped".

I tried an older private version of my app in NEXUS 7 tablet and it was success with the only difference that I do not display toast messages. Toast message indicates if connection of wi-fi or mobile is available or not in user's device. Please find below the code:

```
private void setUpMap() {
   ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

 if (conMan != null) {
//mobile
NetworkInfo.State mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState();

//wifi
NetworkInfo.State wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState();


if (mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connection available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connection not available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
} // end if
else 
{  //do nothing
}

 // set position, title, snippet and icon for each marker
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(X, Y)).title("NAME").snippet("SURNAME").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location_icon)));

.....
...
}  // END SETUPMAP
```

If conMan is not null then do the checks (wi-fi or mobile), otherwise do nothing and continue to load markers on map. For NEXUS 7 the check should enter to else since conMan is null, and should continuw to load markers. But still is not working, the app is crashing in NEXUS 7 .. Could you please advice me what to do?

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity      
ComponentInfo{project.name/project.name.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at project.name.MapsActivity.setUpMap(MapsActivity.java:147)
at project.name.MapsActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded(MapsActivity.java:64)
at project.name.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:43)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
... 11 more
```

Here is the line 147:

```
private void setUpMap() {


    ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (conMan != null) {            //line 147
        //mobile
        NetworkInfo.State mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState();
```

Comment: MapsActivity line 147!

Comment: line 147 is the null check:  if (conMan != null) {

Comment: means your `conMan` is null.

Comment: @Thanos : it's not true null check cannot throw NPE.maybe you have to build your project again

Comment: Is your code in fragment?? Also check you have given Access network permission to manifest file.

Comment: so add first if (conMan == null) { do nothing/print message } else { do the wi-fi / mobile checks} . correct? if not please advice.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Answer (score 1):

Nexus 7 wifi will return null on :

```
conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
```

because its wifi and doesn't support mobile data , 
so you have to check that line for being Null then get it's state.

```
ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if(conMan != null)
            {
                NetworkInfo inf = conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

                if(inf != null) {
                    NetworkInfo.State mobile = inf.getState();
                }
            }
```

Comment: thanks! it seems it works in tablet device without SIM